# Multilingual literature not getting available on site

Tags: cme, 2009, localization

Kindly help me on that i do have multilingual literature say for X country and localized that component, after republished the same component on language level, the literature is not available on site for that country even for rest of country sites the other languages literature are available

Comment: Hi Nitin, this question is a little vague and is likely to be closed. Could you add the version of Tridion and as much detail as you can about your problem and what you have done to solve it please?

Comment: Hi i am using version 2009, i have localized the component on language base then uploaded the literature and republished the same after that product.xml republished but unfortunately literature for only one language is not getting display on site but the literature for other languages are getting displayed, i am facing an issue  with only that x language country site

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that you may have a blueprint priority conflict somewhere, or an additional localization of your component. In Tridion 2009 I don't know how to check this easily, in Tridion 2011 and higher you can see the whole blueprint hierarchy for a given component...

Can you:

- Open the page that contains the component **in the publication that you're publishing from**
- Double check that the component used on that page is in the language you expect?

Another option is to:

- Get the tcm URI of the component you localized (for instance "tcm:12-123")
- Find the publication ID of the publication that you are publishing from (for instance "tcm:0-15-1")
- Try to open the component in that publication (enter "tcm:15-123" in the search box)
- Select to open the Local component in read-only mode (instead of open parent)
- Check that the component is in the correct language

If you do have a blueprint priority conflict you may need to work with a System Administrator to figure out what's wrong there. You could perhaps have another localized version of the same component in the blueprint tree:

- tcm:12-123 (localized version with correct language)
- tcm:13-123 (localized version from before translation, with ORIGINAL language)
- tcm:15-123 (version used in the page, inheriting from tcm:13-123 instead of tcm:12-123)

Answer (score 1):

Did you ever see any localised content within your 'X' website?

Could it be that you are using SDL Tridion Content Delivery (or a Content Delivery framework like DD4T) and you are still referencing content from your 'master' publication?  It's easy to make this mistake if you're copying the application from your master to a number of child websites.

This could be the likely cause if you've one website that is showing the 'master' content but your other localised website show the translated content.